# I'm writing a C# windows service to constantly read from 4 different hardware devices. Timers or threads with loops/sleeping?

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer, camera

I'm writing a Windows Service to run in the background and read data off (via provided C# sdk) of 4 separate USB camera modules which are triggered externally via hardware. I'd like to make relatively modular pieces so we can operate with more or fewer camera modules with ease. As such I'll probably make a "camera reader" class and create as many as I need within the context of the service. For the sake of timing, I also need a separate entity to take all the images collected and write them to disk.

The question I have, not having developed a Windows service or written C# before, is this: Is there any real difference between having such a class contain a timer object and a tick function as opposed to having the class start a thread which loops checking the cameras and calculating a sleep period to do it at regular intervals? The Windows Service examples I keep finding all use Timers for ongoing background tasks.

I have the same question for the entity that writes to disk. That could also be either another timer or a thread, though I'd lean towards thread there as I'd have a queue with a semaphore for it to pull it's work from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ways will work fine (as long as you don't use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which needs a message loop to work).

This is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) says about timers:

> The .NET Framework Class Library includes four classes named Timer, each of which offers different functionality:
>
> - System.Timers.Timer, which fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. **The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.**
> - System.Threading.Timer, which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. **Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.**
> - System.Windows.Forms.Timer, a Windows Forms component that fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment.
> - System.Web.UI.Timer, an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.

So, use whatever floats your boat!

As for writing the data to disk, having a dedicated thread that keeps a queue and writes the files out one at a time sounds good to me!